# What is DM device?

Tags: shutdown, devices

A message could be seen when system shuts down, which is "Failure-finalizing DM device."

What is DM device and how can I solve the problem?

HELLOVENUS, Fantagio

Comment: I have the same issue in Kubuntu 20.04. I've found two questions like this so far, and none have answers.